# Integrate Tensorflow with Drupal

Tags: drupal, tensorflow, drupal-8, tensorflow-serving

I want to use some tensorflow models from drupal. I know that tensorflow has tensorflow serving, and a model can be exported and then one can get a prediction using bazel. 
A simple way of using tensorflow model from drupal is executing bash command in php using exec function.

Are there other ways to do that? maybe there is a http request way?

Comment: you can use a REST API to execute via post/put/get request

Comment: as far as i understood tensorflow serving the client is also a python script, but the model is loaded in a server with host and a port. so i need to execute that python script. is there a way to connect to that server via php?

Comment: Have you found a solution @mosnow_ion?